# JRuby + Glassfish Gem + Bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glassfish, jruby

I'm getting the following error when trying to use JRuby, Bundler, the Glassfish gem, and Rails 2.3.9 in production:

```
Could not load the bundler gem. Install it with `gem install bundler`
```

No matter what I try, this happens. I deploy via capistrano, and the bundle gets created in the shared directory of the app. Bundler is installed and I can see it in gem env.

I'm starting the app via

```
cd #{current_path}; bundle exec glassfish -P #{shared_path}/pids/glassfish.pid"
```

The server does start, but I get a "Something went wrong" when I go to the app URL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually is no longer relevant as I've moved on from those particular versions and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Robert,

First off, I assume that you have followed instructions in http://gembundler.com/rails23.html. If not, make sure you do.

Second, make sure you are running `bundle` with JRuby:

```
jruby -S bundle exec glassfish
```

Third, `-P` requires daemonization, so make sure you have that option turned on (either with `-d` flag, or in `glassfish.yml`).

Comment: I did. The app works fine under MRI. I'll try running bundle exec that way and see if it changes. My yml config has daemon enabled. I'll comment again shortly

Comment: Running it with jruby -S made no difference in this case

Comment: If I turn off the daemon setting, the app doesn't error on Bundler. It errors on another bit of code that's in the app itself (which doesn't error under MRI, but that's a different thing completely). Any ideas on why that would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest JRuby 1.5.5 or master. We saw a similar problem with both bundle exec and daemonize modes due to a bug in the way JRuby was propagating the environment (or not, in this case).

Comment: I have the latest JRuby: jruby 1.5.5 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 249) (2010-11-10 4bd4200) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_22) [amd64-java]
 and I downloaded the latest glassfish gem from BanzaiMan's github clone and I still get the same problem.